# Thanks for your answer/Thanks for your answers

Tags: singular-vs-plural

If I want to thank to **10 people**, each person gave me **one answer**, what should I say to them? Is it "thanks for your answer" or "thanks for your answers"?

Basically, I've accepted **10 answers** in this situation and I'm confused about choosing which one is more appropriate "answer" or "answers"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are writing one thank you message to be seen by all ten, then there are 10 answers, so use the plural "answers". The same applies if a message is sent to two or more of the ten people.

If you are writing ten individual messages each addressed to one person, then each message is about one answer, so use the singular "answer".